# mySQL with EF causing MySqlConnection is already in use error

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

```
        public IActionResult ListUsers()
    {
        try
        {

            var users = _userManager.Users.Select(i => new UsersViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = i.FirstName,
                LastName = i.LastName,
                Email = i.Email,
                PhoneNumber = i.PhoneNumber,
                EmailConfirmed = i.EmailConfirmed,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = i.PhoneNumberConfirmed,
                LockoutEnabled = i.LockoutEnabled,
                AccessFailedCount = i.AccessFailedCount,
                Role = string.Join(",", _userManager.GetRolesAsync(i).Result.ToArray())
            }).ToList();
            return ok(users);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
```

Its causing error saying

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (This MySqlConnection is already in use. See https://fl.vu/mysql-conn-reuse)'

my mysql connection is as below

```
        public static void ConfigureSqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) =>
        services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(options =>
```

options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 22))));

```
    public static void ConfigureRepositoryManager(this IServiceCollection services) =>
       services.AddTransient<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();
```